# Align Div to the bottom of the Parent div

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to align a div to the bottom of the parent div. An example is on the screen below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBn4i.png)

these div are inside an grid, why is the button inside the div not sticked to the bottom.

Comment: you should  put some codes in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.parent {
  height: 400px;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: end;
  justify-content: center;
}

.child {
  width: 90%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: cyan;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use CSS flexbox layout rules. Look at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ for a great guide.